# Using WCF Services with Android

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I have been struggling the entire day to connect an Android app to a simple WCF Service (It is a proof of concept app).
I have looked everywhere for help, but I can still cannot come right.

I want to return a string when a GetHello() service contract method is called.

The service is as follows:

using System.ServiceModel;

```
namespace MyWcfServiceLibrary
{
[ServiceContract]
&// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
public interface IInventoryDTOService
$// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetHello();

    [OperationContract]
    int GetNumber(bool getPositiveNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    InventoryDTO GetInventoryDTO(int id);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

}

```
The service impelementation is a follows:



 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MyWcfServiceLibrary
    {
        // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.

        public class InventoryDTOService : IInventoryDTOService
        {

            public string GetHello()
            {
                return "Hello From WCF";
            }

            public int GetNumber(bool getPositiveNumber)
            {
                int returnInt = -55;

                if (getPositiveNumber == true)
                {
                    returnInt = 55;
                }
                return returnInt;
            }

            public InventoryDTO GetInventoryDTO(int id)
            {
                InventoryDTO dto = new InventoryDTO()
                {
                    Donor = "Harold Potter",
                    InventoryId = 22,
                    PerishDate = DateTime.Now

                };

                return dto;
            }

        }
    }
```

The Android java is as follows:

package FoodVault.Mobile.DemoWCFClient;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;



    public class DemoWCFClientActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */


         private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetHello";
         private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
         private static final String URL = "http://41.3.235.46/Service/InventoryDTO.svc";
         private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetHello";

        EditText editText;
        Button buttonUpdate;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            buttonUpdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
            buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            //   request.addProperty("name", "Qing");

               SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
               envelope.dotNet = true;
               envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapObject response = null;
                    response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                    String resultData= response.getProperty(0).toString();              
                    editText.setText(resultData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        }
```

The WSDL:

```
 wsdl:definitions name="InventoryDTOService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    −
    <wsdl:types>
    −
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://41.4.90.184/Service/InventoryDTO.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://41.4.90.184/Service/InventoryDTO.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://41.4.90.184/Service/InventoryDTO.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWcfServiceLibrary"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    −
    <wsdl:message name="IInventoryDTOService_GetHello_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetHello"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    −
    <wsdl:message name="IInventoryDTOService_GetHello_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetHelloResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    −
    <wsdl:message name="IInventoryDTOService_GetNumber_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetNumber"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    −
    <wsdl:message name="IInventoryDTOService_GetNumber_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetNumberResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    −
    <wsdl:message name="IInventoryDTOService_GetInventoryDTO_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetInventoryDTO"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    −
    <wsdl:message name="IInventoryDTOService_GetInventoryDTO_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetInventoryDTOResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    −
    <wsdl:portType name="IInventoryDTOService">
    −
    <wsdl:operation name="GetHello">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetHello" message="tns:IInventoryDTOService_GetHello_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetHelloResponse" message="tns:IInventoryDTOService_GetHello_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    −
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNumber">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetNumber" message="tns:IInventoryDTOService_GetNumber_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetNumberResponse" message="tns:IInventoryDTOService_GetNumber_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    −
    <wsdl:operation name="GetInventoryDTO">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetInventoryDTO" message="tns:IInventoryDTOService_GetInventoryDTO_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetInventoryDTOResponse" message="tns:IInventoryDTOService_GetInventoryDTO_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    −
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IInventoryDTOService" type="tns:IInventoryDTOService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    −
    <wsdl:operation name="GetHello">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetHello" style="document"/>
    −
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    −
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    −
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNumber">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetNumber" style="document"/>
    −
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    −
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    −
    <wsdl:operation name="GetInventoryDTO">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IInventoryDTOService/GetInventoryDTO" style="document"/>
    −
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    −
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    −
    <wsdl:service name="InventoryDTOService">
    −
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IInventoryDTOService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IInventoryDTOService">
    <soap:address location="http://41.4.90.184/Service/InventoryDTO.svc/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWcfServiceLibrary/InventoryDTOService/""/>
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

When I call the androidTransport.call(...) method I keep getting a socket timeout exception. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have access issues to the IP number. Make sure it is reachable e.g. via the browser on the device or emulator. The ksoap2-android website also has more links that should help with that.

Comment: I have solved the socket timeout exception, I needed to use the IP address: 10.0.2.2 using this resource: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias. Now I keep getting an XMLPullParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44eb0ca8)

Comment: If I type in the URL of the service: http://10.0.2.2:80/Service/InventoryDTO.svc in the emulators browser it is visible now.

Comment: you should accept my answer then. The pull parser is a different problem. Read on the wiki on how to debug your request and response xml..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Android platform but I once worked out that a Java client connects to WCF service, it worked well using Glassfish (maybe, I don't remember it).

I may give you some suggestion. You may turn on the WCF Trace and see what goes wrong on the server side, the log may show you something.

Answer (score 0):

In my project i was getting  SoketTimeoutException when i tried it on GPRS[Slow network] and that was working fine for wifi.

Also turn off your firewall and disable your antivirus if you have installed, then it will work.